# Google cloud Function - Golag no matching function found with name

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to run my function on GCP via gitlab CI, but it returns the following error:

```
Function failed to start: no matching function found with name: "RunUsers"
```

path: test/function.go

file name "function.go"

deploy

```
gcloud functions deploy test  
        --runtime=go116
        --entry-point=RunUsers
        --region=us-east1
        --source=.
        --trigger-http
```

```
package function

import (
    "io"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-go/functions"

    _ "github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-go/funcframework"
)

func init() {
    functions.HTTP("RunUsers", RunUsers)
}

func RunUsers(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    io.WriteString(w, "OK")
}
```

Should I remove .mod in
`.gcloudignore`  file?

gcloudignore:

```
# This file specifies files that are *not* uploaded to Google Cloud
# using gcloud. It follows the same syntax as .gitignore, with the addition of
# "#!include" directives (which insert the entries of the given .gitignore-style
# file at that point).
#
# For more information, run:
#   $ gcloud topic gcloudignore
#
.gcloudignore
# If you would like to upload your .git directory, .gitignore file or files
# from your .gitignore file, remove the corresponding line
# below:
.git
.gitignore

tests/
README.md
Makefile
env/
*.json
sonar-project.properties
.gitlab-ci.yml
cmd/
*.mod
```

Has anyone gone through this problem?

Comment: you must share the go.mod file. and your gcloudignore doesn't send it.

Answer (score 1):

You are specifying the entrypoint as:

```
--entry-point=RunUsers
```

The function declaration is:

```
func runUsers(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request)
```

Notice the difference in **case** for the function names: `runUsers` versus `RunUsers`.

Comment: In the Google Cloud Platform github documentation, this format is used https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-go

Comment: @ANDERSONMANOELPATRIGNANI -Golang is case-sensitive for name resolution. Use the same case. You can create an Issue Track for documentation problems here: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers

Comment: Even after changing the code, I still have the same problem.

Comment: @ANDERSONMANOELPATRIGNANI - update your question with the deploy command, code and new error message.

Comment: @ANDERSONMANOELPATRIGNANI seems right. Functions should look for the function as the name registered by `functions.HTTP` function.

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurred in the deploy, the code in was correct and the function working

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

When trying to run the code locally I encountered the same error:

```
Serving function: "Execute"2023/02/06 11:57:36 funcframework.Start: no matching function found with name: "Execute"
```

The solution required including a `func init()` in my code (along with the `cmd/main.go` file), see documentation:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-go#quickstart-hello-world-on-your-local-machine